# Touch gesture problems in React Native with Appsee

Tags: ios, react-native, appsee

When I enable Appsee in my react-native app, I experience bugs with components which handle gestures. Simple example would be a navigator:

```
const routes = [
    {text:"1"},
    {text:"2"},
    {text:"3"}
];
const {Navigator} = require('react-native-deprecated-custom-components');
return <Navigator
    renderScene={r => (
        <View>
            <Text>{ r.text }</Text>
        </View>
    )}
    initialRouteStack={routes}
    initialRoute={routes[0]}
    onDidFocus={() => this.forceUpdate()}
    configureScene={() => Navigator.SceneConfigs.HorizontalSwipeJump}
/>
```

What I see is that if I try to swipe the navigator quickly, it gets stuck, and I have to release the touch to make it responsive again. However, if I first press the component and only start moving finger after a second or so, then it goes smoothly and I can then switch to fast swiping without problems (still holding touch). In other words, the following happens: when I begin touch already swiping, the component moves a little and then freezes until touch is released.

I mentioned `Navigator` because this is the easiest example. I also have some range sliders, which have the same behaviour. However, scrollviews work just fine.

This is the way I enable Appsee from cocoapods (nothing else except `#import` and key in info plist):

```
[Fabric with:@[[Crashlytics class], [Appsee class]]];
```

Replacing that line with `[Fabric with:@[[Crashlytics class]]];` resolves the issue.

This issue does not happen on Android.

I have two independent questions:
1) Is this problem react-native-specific? Because no way that Appsee just breaks regular apps.
2) Can anything be done about it?

Comment: You should contact their support team at support@appsee.com.

Answer (score 0):

The problem arised because of the way I installed Appsee. With react-native package [`react-native-appsee`](https://www.appsee.com/docs/ios/reactnative) has to be used instead of just enabling it in AppDelegate.